# Why "frame of reference" can apparently mean two different things?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, mathematical-physics, coordinate-systems

There are several things about frame of reference in physics which I know.

1. We may work in $\mathbb R^3,$ but this set is annoying because it has an origin. In physics we wish to have a decentralized theory where laws are independent of the choice of origin, so we would instead work on a (Riemannian) manifold $M$ with a metric $g.$
2. A **frame of reference** means a one-parameter subgroup $\phi_t$ of the group of isometries of $M$. This should be **different** from the concept of a **local coordinate frame** of a manifold, which is also called a "frame" for some reason.
3. The above idea can be generalised. See [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_frame#Method_of_the_moving_frame).
4. **However,** the first sentence in [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_of_reference) says that a frame is a coordinate system with reference points. **This definition is also very commonly seen in many books.**

So, we end up with two definitions of frames of reference: (by vector I mean either tangent vector of a manifold, or simply a vector in $\mathbb R^n$)

1. **The one-parameter subgroup version.** A frame of reference is (at least in the definition) **not** a set of coordinates, but a function/an action of a Lie group that dictates how old points are changed into new ones in new frame.
2. **The coordinate version.** A frame of reference is a system of coordinates that describes the system. Saying that it is **a change of coordinates** in some way implies that (tangent) vectors/points **themselves** should be **"independent" of the coordinate/frame in some sense** (not always "independent" - the acceleration vector in rotating frame is different from that in an inertial frame). This is very different from the first definition, where vectors **themselves** are changed.

**So, why do we have two very different meanings for "frame of reference"?** In practical application of frames, we never seem to run into this problem.

Comment: Interesting thoughts. My own feeling is that human languages, and particularly English perhaps more than some others, are just very overloaded in terms of what one wants to talk about. It isn't too surprising to me that different groups of people have landed on "frame of reference" as a term for potentially distinguishable concepts/motivations. Some people put varying or distinct levels of continuity / differentiability into their discussion of planar curves. What's the harm? It's not like we're chemists, where referring to different compounds by the same name might end up poisoning somebody.

Comment: They are both the same. There are still three spatial coordinates being parametrized by one parameter, to describe the frame of an object in motion. So frame always refers to a coordinate system, mathematically, but terminology can get sloppy and instead frame could refer to the sequence of origins that forms a curve.

Comment: @leslietownes The interesting thing is that we are likely to agree on the meaning of a "frame" in most situations despite this difference. Maybe that needs some explanation.

Comment: @MaJoad respectfully I disagree. I would not generally understand what anybody meant by a "frame" without them spelling it out. Maybe it's a choice of basis at one point, or maybe it's a family of choices of basis, or maybe it's even more than that. I just wouldn't know. The main unknowns for me would be what properties of a choice of basis for a tangent vector space at one point are intended to be propagated to another, and how.

Comment: @leslietownes Yes. We learn the meaning of the author in the context. Note that the one-parameter subgroup version does not even need a basis.